# React Native, error looping through an array (Failed child context type:)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the below code to loop through an array.

```
export default function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState([
    {name:'a'},{name:'b'}
  ]);
  return (
    <View >
      <FlatList
        data={x}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

The above code gives below error

```
Warning: Failed child context type: Invalid child context `virtualizedCell.cellKey` of type `number` supplied to `CellRenderer`, expected `string`.
```

When I change

```
 <FlatList
            data={x}
            renderItem={(item) => {
              return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
            }}
          />
```

To

```
 <FlatList
            data={x}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              return <Text>{item.name}</Text>;
            }}
          />
```

The code is correct now and it works, see I changed (item) to ({item}) *added curly braces* .

Why is so ?

Comment: See in [`FlatList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) documentation how it works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is clearly given by the documentation - a suitable answer to the OPs *why is this so* question is - *because that's how it works*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see link document https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html
renderItem

```
renderItem({ item, index, separators });
```

- item: (Object): The item from data being rendered.
- index (number): The index corresponding to this item in the data array.
- separators (Object)

- highlight (Function)
- unhighlight (Function)
- updateProps (Function)
  select (enum('leading', 'trailing'))
  newProps (Object)

Example usage:

```
<FlatList
  ItemSeparatorComponent={
    Platform.OS !== 'android' &&
    (({ highlighted }) => (
      <View
        style={[
          style.separator,
          highlighted && { marginLeft: 0 }
        ]}
      />
    ))
  }
  data={[{ title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1' }]}
  renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
      key={item.key}
      onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
      onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
      onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use the key prop flour. try again with the code below

```
<FlatList
    data={x}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <Text key={index}>{item.name}</Text>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `FlatList` returns item object in which their is your items or array to be render!

its like

```
{ 
 items: {
   {name:'a'},
   {name:'b'}
  }
}
```

so we have to go to item first by destructuring by {item} and then access the inner objects.

Hope it will make understanding !